# Examining movement in rankings as meaningful

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking, discrete-data

I have a lot of dust on my statistical knowledge and I'm hoping for some wisdom. I believe I am looking for a statistical test of rankings or discreet data.

I have monthly tracking data for 5 people rated on performance on a 5-point scale (strongly agree, mostly agree, ...) .

The average rating for each person in each month is not statistically different than others. That is, the 5 people are relatively close to each other and the sample size (about 300) is not large enough to create a small enough margin of error. This lack of separation remains even when grouping months together whether in 3 months, 6 months or, even, all 12 months.

However, a graph shows a interesting story. One person, let's call him Bob, was ranked 5th for the first 6 months and then moved up to 1st over the second 6 months. (data: 5th, 5th, 5th, 5th, 5th, 5th, 4th, 3rd, 3rd, 2nd, 2nd, 1st). In comparison, the other people's data moves up and down without readily identifiable pattern.

Is there a statistical test that allows me to state that this is a meaningful move?

Comment: Can you paste in the plot & the data?

Comment: I can, but it will take a bit of time. I'm off today and don't have the data with me. It will either be in about 8 hours when someone is free to send it to me or tomorrow when I'm back in.

Sorry for not planning ahead.